# Angular 2 or 4 multiselect calendar

Tags: angular, datepicker, calendar

Hi I am new to angular 4 , I want to use multi select date picker in a year calendar.I am trying with the existing ones but only angular 1 i can find.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this one](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar)?  It uses date ranges, you can learn more about the libary with the link.